# Can we say 'he is stopped'?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, past-participles

Can we say 'He is stopped' in place of 'He has stopped'?

'Stop',here is an Intransitive verb, so I think it would be correct to make its past participle (stopped) and use it as a Predicative adjective like 'he is stopped'.

Comment: I think as a general rule, yes, I think you can interchange them. But it might depend on how you are using it - do you have a usage example?

Comment: No and I have never seen a sentence like that......I just want to know what sense do past participle form of intransitive verbs give when used as Predicative adjective. Another verb is 'come', it's also intransitive but we can only say 'he has come', not 'he is come'(it sounds funny). But we can say 'he is gone'.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - *Stopped* is an adjective in *He is stopped*, but a verb in *He has stopped*. It is defined as a verb or an adjective in here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stopped

Both are grammatically correct, and I think can be applied fairly interchangably, depending on the context and the point you want to get across.